# Regex apply - % match

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

I have the next regex, that parses text and finds matches between `{word1|word2}` etc.

It is done to make word rotation inside the sentence. `word1` or `word2` will be taken randomly.

Current regex is:

```
\{(\w\s?|\|)*\}|\{(\W\s?|\|)*\}
```

The sample message is:

```
Please take a look on this {information|website|web site}.
```

It will work fine and will match `{information|website|web site}`.

But if we add `%` to any word variant - regex will not work. For example, it will not work for: `Please take a look on this {100% information|website|web site}.`

I have checked different kinds of regex, including adding `%?` to the expression, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\{[^}]+?\}
```

or

```
{.*?}
```

You can simply use this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/nS2lT4/8